# Select 2 dates where an event start and stop

Tags: php

How can I echo something only between two dates? I want to add a `id=""` on holidays like christams, but I dont want the `id=""` to be gone a split second after the time I set it to echo on. I need to be able to set it like `>=2016.10.10` and `<=2016.10.24` in some way (if I got that example right).

heres my code for christams:

```
<?php 
$christams = date("Y")."-12-23 23:59:59";
if($server_time == $christams){
  echo'<div id="snow"></div>';
}else{}
?>
```

btw, `$server_time` is defined in head and is currently empty, but its supposed to set the server time since I rather work with 1 timezone then 100

Comment: Convert the strings to an integers using `strtotime` then you can use `<=` so after christmas it doesn't display, or whatever you want to do after/before christmas. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php Examples: https://eval.in/664823, https://eval.in/664822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `strtotime` to convert your dates:

```
$server_time = strtotime("2016-10-12");

$date1 = strtotime("2016-10-10");
$date2 = strtotime("2016-10-14");

if ($server_time >= $date1 && $server_time < $date2) {
    echo'<div id="snow"></div>';
} else {

}
```

This example will echo your `div`.

Comment: you answor works but do you know how i can use php to set the timezone that whould work with this code? the function i used on past websites dont seem to work with this method since it uses `date()` instead of `strtotime()`